# Compilers and Instruction sets

Tags: c, compiler-construction, cpu, instruction-set

> "C is a genereal purpose language, not tied to a particular system"
>   The C programming Language, BRIAN W KERNIGHAN & DENNIS M. RITCHIE

Yet with the right compiler we can make a .exe which runs on every Windows machine, which in turn means on every CPU Windows runs on.

So my question is: does every x86-64 CPU (Intel or AMD) use the same instruction set ? (yes, I could make a comparison...) if not, then I'll have to assume that the compiler detects what CPU we're running and uses the right instruction set during compile time.

Am I totally mistaken ?

I barely know what I'm talking about so please bear with me.
Just a dude trying to look under the hood.

Thank you

Comment: Very rougly said: yes,  all x86-64 CPU (Intel or AMD) use the same instruction set.

Comment: Given that Windows also runs on ARM, "with the right compiler we can make a .exe which runs on every Windows machine, which in turn means on every CPU Windows runs on" is not true. The same native executable can't run both on Windows/ARM and Windows/x86-64.

Comment: Should've written "32 and 64 bit CPU's"

Comment: I don't understand the confusion. The **language/code** is not tied to any particular system. **A binary that you compile for a particular class of system** is. The language is not equivalent to things compiled by a particular implementation of that language.

Comment: " the compiler detects what CPU we're running and uses the right instruction set during compile time. "  - no, you tell the compiler about the target CPU with a compiler option. The machine you're compiling on does not define the machine you're targeting for your compiled code.

Comment: Every x86-64 CPU supports a lowest-common-denominator subset of instructions, which is to say the basic scalar instructions plus everything up to SSE2. Some compilers, either _automatically_ **or** _when told to do so_, will either _compile for a given CPU_, **or** _detect the CPU on which the compiler is run and compile specifically for it_, **or** _compile several versions for different CPUs and add some extra code in the executable to detect the machine's CPU and decide which version to run *at runtime*._ It very much depends on the compiler and the options you give it.

Comment: A "system" is more that the CPU, it includes the memory, I/O and various implementation specific architecture.  Windows is not a platform, it is an OS.  Even using the same instruction set can have different outcomes -especially with I/O.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intel makes many different processor models that share a core instruction set of the “x86-64” family (and additional processor models that do not). Even among the processors with the shared core instructions, there are variations. Newer models may have instructions that older models did not, and some parts of the instruction set may be on certain models and not others.

Some instructions even behave differently on different processors.

When you compile a program, the compiler “targets” a particular combination of instruction subsets. This means the instructions in those subsets are available for the compiler to use when it is generating code. The compiler might or might not use any particular instruction or subset depending on its needs or choices when compiling a particular program. The resulting program is then suitable for processor models with the targeted instructions and not for other models (unless the compiler happened not to use any of the instructions not on those models, even though it could have).

Often, the default setting for the compiler‘s target is either a processor model like the one you are running on or some typical selection of instruction subsets that is common for modern processor models. The target may also be selected based on other settings you give the compiler, such as asking it to target a particular version of an operating system. However, you can pass the compiler switches to tell it to compile for entirely different targets, even for entirely different architectures, such as compiling for an ARM processor while running on an Intel processor.

Software is also part of a computer system, so the executable file the compiler produces may also depend on certain software libraries being available at run-time or certain operating system features being available.